# Git branch merged on local repo but still visible on Github

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I'm using [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for my project, and have completed the `git flow feature finish` step that merged my feature branch into my `develop` branch.

I then performed `git push` to GitHub, but on GitHub I still see the feature branch as well as `develop`.

When I run `git branch` locally, I only see `develop` and `master`, which is what I'd expect.

How can I remove the branch from GitHub? I could cope with this one, but if this happens for every feature I'll end up with a massive list of old branches.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the `origin` remote refers to your GitHub respository, you can delete the merged branch with:

```
git push origin :name-of-now-merged-branch
```

To explain that syntax further, when you do:

```
git push origin some-branch
```

... the `some-branch` parameter is actually a "[refspec](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#OPTIONS)" which defines a mapping between a source name and a destination name, usually of the form `<source-name>:<destination-name>`.  If there's no `:` in the refspec, it assumes that you mean `some-branch:some-branch`.  The way to say "I just want to delete the remote branch" is to miss out the `<source-name>` completely, just ending up with `:` followed by the remote branch name.

Comment: I.e. is that command essentially pushing the fact that the branch has been merged? In which case, I wonder why `git push` with no args didn't push it?

Comment: @NeilBarnwell: I've expanded on that syntax in my answer - you can delete any remote branch that way (unless the remote repository disallows it), and it doesn't have anything to do with whether it's been merged or not.

Answer (score 1):

Check which remote branches are available

```
git branch -r
```

Then you can delete the remote branch with:

```
git push origin :branchname
```

To delete the branch local

```
git branch -d branchname
```

Edit:

http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/02/push-and-delete-branches.html

Answer (score 0):

[As per this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406458/remove-merged-branches-from-github) if you do `git push --all --prune`, it will automatically remove all those merged branches without you having to go in manually and removing each one.

Comment: Careful, this deletes *all* branches on the remote that you do not have locally.

Comment: @BudgieInWA Ahh, good point!  I pull copies of all branches in my workflow, but I could see that being an issue for some!