# Remove Merged Branches from Github

Tags: git, github

I use `git flow` to handle branching for my project.  It's great for streamlining the branching process, however it also leads to having a ton of branches being displayed in the dropdown on the project's page.

Is there a way of cleaning up that branch list to only display non-merged branches without losing history?  [Other examples I've seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468200/git-branch-merged-on-local-repo-but-still-visible-on-github) appear to remove history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have cleaned up your local copy of the repo to your liking, you can delete *all* branches on the remote that you do not have locally with the command

```
git push --all --prune
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Short, sweet, and did exactly what I needed.

Comment: This command attempts to delete *all* branches on the remote that you do not have locally.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete a **merged** local branch with

```
git branch -d <branchname>
```

You'll get an error message if you try to delete an unmerged branch.

To delete the same branch on the remote (origin) repository you can execute

```
git push origin :<branchname>
```